# Vagrant/VirtualBox can't resolve some domains from w/in VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, apt, resolv.conf, vagrant

Just trying out VirtualBox & Vagrant and my initial `lucid64` VM can't resolve `us.archive.ubuntu.com` but *can* resolve `security.ubuntu.com`, `google.com` and `www.apple.com` (but not `apple.com` w/out the `www`?!?!).

The *host* that the VM is running in *can* resolve `us.archive.ubuntu.com` just fine as well as every other domain.

No idea what's going on?!?

```
vagrant@lucid64:~$ sudo apt-get install dkms -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fakeroot make patch
Suggested packages:
  make-doc diffutils-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dkms fakeroot make patch
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
Need to get 458kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,359kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main make 3.81-7ubuntu1
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main patch 2.6-2ubuntu1
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main dkms 2.1.1.2-2ubuntu1
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main fakeroot 1.14.4-1ubuntu1
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/make-dfsg/make_3.81-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/patch/patch_2.6-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.1.1.2-2ubuntu1_all.deb  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot_1.14.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Vanilla installation. My first attempt. Following instructions in a Deploying Rails book.

Edit: Adding `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
vagrant@lucid64:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 10.0.2.3
domain mydomain.com
search mydomain.com
```

Also some dig info:

```
vagrant@lucid64:~$ dig us.archive.ubuntu.com
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P1 <<>> us.archive.ubuntu.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

but it seems to resolve the domain name when the `+trace` flag is used?!? (or am I reading this wrong?)

```
vagrant@lucid64:~$ dig us.archive.ubuntu.com +trace

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P1 <<>> us.archive.ubuntu.com +trace
;; global options: +cmd
.           199183  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           199183  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           199183  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           199183  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           199183  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           199183  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           199183  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           199183  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           199183  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           199183  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           199183  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           199183  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           199183  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
;; Received 256 bytes from 10.0.2.3#53(10.0.2.3) in 1 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
;; Received 499 bytes from 193.0.14.129#53(k.root-servers.net) in 191 ms

ubuntu.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.canonical.com.
ubuntu.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.canonical.com.
ubuntu.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns3.canonical.com.
;; Received 151 bytes from 192.42.93.30#53(g.gtld-servers.net) in 46 ms

us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.192
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.193
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.91.13
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.91.23
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.91.24
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.91.25
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.151
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.152
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.153
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.154
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.155
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.176
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.177
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.179
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.180
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.181
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.182
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.183
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  600 IN  A   91.189.92.184
ubuntu.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.canonical.com.
ubuntu.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns3.canonical.com.
ubuntu.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.canonical.com.
;; Received 455 bytes from 91.189.95.3#53(ns2.canonical.com) in 183 ms
```

Edit2 - more dig:

```
vagrant@lucid64:~$ dig @10.0.2.3 security.ubuntu.com +short
91.189.92.181
91.189.92.184
91.189.92.151
91.189.92.166
vagrant@lucid64:~$ dig @10.0.2.3 us.archive.ubuntu.com
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P1 <<>> @10.0.2.3 us.archive.ubuntu.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: What's the network configuration look like on the VM?  What DNS server(s) are you using?  Do you have reliable connectivity to them?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not even certain how to tell. I'm new to Ubuntu and Vagrant. I'll add `/etc/resolv.conf` info (above). Lemme know where to look if you want more…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have "magically" resolved itself when I upgraded the host Mac OS from Lion (10.7.4) to Mountain Lion (10.8) so not gonna waste anymore cycles on it..

Comment: I have the same issue, it seems it happens only on first run, just like if DNS isn't ready, and when I "vagrant provision" a second time, hosts are resolved.

Answer (score 13):

I solved that issue by adding the lines below to my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
end
```

Below is the whole of it:

```
$setup = <<SCRIPT
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
SCRIPT

$dependencies = <<SCRIPT
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y postgresql libpq-dev
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y python-dev libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y python-virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|

    config.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'

    # config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.90"

    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", id: "vagrant-root", disabled: true
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/siaq"

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.name = "siaq"
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "512"]
    end

    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $setup
    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $dependencies
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's because you can't contact the DNS server set at all, and it's trying to use the root hints (which, in my experience, are very unreliable for end-users). Can you ping it? Are you set to bridged mode, with no firewalls getting in the way?

Comment: no i cannot ping the `10.0.2.3` host. It appears that the *VirtualBox* (or *Vagrant*) has assigned the VM an IP of `10.0.2.2`. The host is at `10.0.1.201`. VB/Vagrant set the *nameserver* to `10.0.2.3` which "works" and resolves some domains (see edit2 above) but not the most important for a Ubuntu box.